# Получить из PPT картинки слайдов на javascript

Tags: node.js, javascript, office

У меня есть сайт на Nodejs

Необходимо из объекта file, который пришел от клиента (ppt), получить, например, массив изображений каждого слайда.

Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите Open Office/LibreOffice. Оно умеет работать с файлами PowerDot. Возможно, Вам достаточно из "напечатать" в postscript (а уж для работы с ps инструментов много).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел только такие варианты, которые бы поддерживали форматы презентаций и PPT, и PPTX.
К сожалению, насколько я понимаю, это облачные решения.

1) **[Aspose for Cloud](http://www.aspose.com/cloud/powerpoint-api.aspx)**

Очень хорошо документирован.
**node.js** есть в списке поддерживаемых платформ.

**Функционал:**

- Создание презентации PowerPoint.
- Конвертирование презентации в следующие форматы: TIFF, PDF, XPS, PPTX, ODP, PPSX,  - PPTM, PPSM, POTX, POTM и HTML.
- Объединение нескольких презентаций.
- Добавление новых слайдов.
- Создание копий существующих слайдов.
- **[Конвертация слайдов в картинки.](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidescloud/Save%20a%20PowerPoint%20Slide%20as%20Image%20with%20Default%20Size)**
- Получение комментариев со слайда.
- Разбор свойств документа.
- Редактирование текста.
- Извлечение информации о формах, шрифтах, форматах и темах из презентации.
- Изменение порядка слайда.
- [**Разбивка презентации PowerPoint на части (1 слайд => 1 картинка)**](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidescloud/Split%20PowerPoint%20Presentations).

**[Ценовая политика](http://www.aspose.com/cloud/pricing.aspx)**
**Есть бесплатный тариф.**

- максимум 100 документов в месяц
- 1000 обращений к API
- максимальный размер документа 1MB

---

2) **[Doxument](http://www.doxument.com/)**

**[Поддерживает конвертацию слайдов презентации PowerPoint в картинки](https://code.google.com/p/doxument/wiki/Documentation?tm=6#Formats)**

**[Doxument REST API Console](http://www.doxument.com/console.jsp)** - можно работать прямо в браузере
**[Doxument REST API PHP5 SDK](https://code.google.com/p/doxument/wiki/SdkForPHP5)** - примеры для написания своего приложения

**[Ценовая политика](http://www.doxument.com/pricing.jsp)**
**Есть бесплатный тариф.**

- доступно 100 обращений к API в сутки

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

можно конвертировать используя LibreOffice из консоли с параметрами --headless и convert-to 
еще  вариант - unoconv

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters/vi
https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv